# NullReferenceException thrown when executing GroupBy queries through Entity Framework Core that worked in older versions of Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

We are converting an old .NET Framework 4.6.1 project to .NET Core 2.2. In the process, we have updated our Entity Framework packages to Entity Framework Core and `EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` to 2.2.6. Unfortunately, this has resulted in a large number of our existing queries that were previously completing successfully throwing `NullReferenceException`.

This seems to be related to the differences in how the two versions of EF are generating the SQL on our SQL Server 2017 Db platform.

The actual EF queries that are now throwing this error typically are of this nature:

```
var query = from c in _workspaceContext.Container
            join ch in _workspaceContext.ContainerHierarchy on c.ContainerPk equals ch.AncestorFk
            join a in _workspaceContext.Asset on ch.ContainerFk equals a.ParentContainerFk
            join cu in _workspaceContext.ContainerUser on new { ContainerKey = ch.ContainerFk, UserKey = userKey } equals new { ContainerKey = cu.ContainerFk, UserKey = cu.UserFk } into cus
            from cu in cus.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join co in _workspaceContext.ContainerOrganisation on ch.ContainerFk equals co.ContainerFk into cos
            from co in cos.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where containerIds.Contains(c.Id) && !a.IsHidden && a.SentByUserFk == null
            select new ContainerAsset
                      {
                            TopLevelContainerId = c.Id,
                            AssetKey = a.AssetPk,
                            ContainerKey = ch.ContainerFk,
                            AssetName = a.Name,
                            CanView = (c.ContainerTypeFk == 3) 
                      };

query = query.GroupBy(x => new
                           {
                               x.TopLevelContainerId,
                               x.ContainerKey,
                               x.CanView
                           }).ToList();
```

Any ideas on why this behavior has changed between EF Core and EF 6? I can fix the issue by loading the expression of the first query into memory before doing the GroupBy in the second query e.g. like this:

```
   query = query.ToList().GroupBy(x => new
            {
                x.TopLevelContainerId,
                x.ContainerKey,
                x.CanView
            }).ToList();
```

Unfortunately doing this in every scenario will have a negative effect on performance.

Comment: EF Core is very, very different from EF. Personally, I don't think EF Core before 3.0 should be used for production, and sometimes I question 3.0, but it vastly improves things like handling `GroupBy` translation to the server. My best guess would be that EF Core (2.2) is automatically handling some of the query client side (it does that when it can't translate) where EF 6.x would do the whole query server-side.